# Running service application response HTTP Status 404

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

I deploy https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/15/library-manager-for-sap-web-ide/ on the sap hana cloud platform and I can see, that the application is running:
[image]

When I click on the application URL it says **HTTP Status 404**.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also run into a similar issue--after I deployed an app, and it says that it is running, when I open the page of the app, I run into HTTP 404. Don't know why. URL is like https://robw3u1-my_user_id-trial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/test/flpSandbox.html.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in an [SAP UI5 course page](https://open.sap.com/courses/ui51/sections/c9e6fb31-3331-4e23-90fa-3a762d9cd8d8/question/5b09f667-6428-443b-b6a3-1d53530ab1d6) and verified it with my application. It mentions that the application URL shown in the cockpit is only the root URL. You need to append an relative path to it. To see your relative path, you can run the application from Web IDE, and then copy the path from the slash after the host name. For example, if the Web IDE test URL is https://webidetesting-trial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/webapp/test/flpSandbox.html#ManageProducts-display, copy the "webapp/test/flpSandbox.html#ManageProducts-display" part and paste it after the application URL.